# How to send multiple messages from model to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model

In my model I have some custom error messages.

This is just a part of my code:

```
if (!array_key_exists($target, $this->errors)) {
    $this->errors = [ $target => '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, we could not connect to your <strong>'. $target .' database</strong>. Plese check your entries and try connecting again.</div>' ];
}

// There is no connection. Display the right error message and return null
if (count($this->errors > 0)) {
    if (count($this->errors == 0)) {
        echo array_values($this->errors)[0];
    }
    elseif (count($this->errors == 1)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, we could not connect to both of your databases. Plese check your entries and try connecting again.</div>';
    }
    elseif (count($this->errors > 1)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Warning: There is an unknown error. For more information please contact the owner of this website.</div>';
    }
    return null;
    echo '<Form Layout>';
}
else {
    return $this->result;
}
```

I don't actually want to echo these error messages in my model. So what is the best way to send them to the view?

Comment: The best way is to handle the errors in your controller and then sending the neccessary message to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!array_key_exists($target, $this->errors)) {
    $this->errors = [ $target => '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, we could not connect to your <strong>'. $target .' database</strong>. Plese check your entries and try connecting again.</div>' ];
}
$aResult[ 'data' ]   = '';
$aResult[ 'errors' ] = '';
// There is no connection. Display the right error message and return null
if (count($this->errors > 0)) {
    if (count($this->errors == 0)) {
        $aResult[ 'errors' ][] = array_values($this->errors)[0];
    }
    elseif (count($this->errors == 1)) {
        $aResult[ 'errors' ][] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, we could not connect to both of your databases. Plese check your entries and try connecting again.</div>';
    }
    elseif (count($this->errors > 1)) {
        $aResult[ 'errors' ][] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Warning: There is an unknown error. For more information please contact the owner of this website.</div>';
    }
    $aResult[ 'errors' ][] =  '<Form Layout>';
}
else {
    $aResult[ 'data' ] = $this->result;
}
return $aResult;

// Then check if $aResults[ 'errors' ] is empty and handle as needed.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vladimir Ramik answered you can just return the error array so you can just call the method from your controller and save it in a variable

```
$this->load->model('modelName');
$x = $this->modelName->method(); // this will hold your error array
```

If you dont want to return the array (although i do beleive it is best) you can save the array from the model directly into a controller array using the `get_instance()` function .

**In your Model:**

```
function methodName() {
    $CI = get_instance();

    $CI->errors[] = 'error message';
}
```

**In you Controller**

```
function fn() {
    $this->load->model('modelName');

    $this->modelName->methodName();

   // after we run the method in the model, we have here in the controller an array named errors.
   // it is best to declare the array on the begining of the class as public errors = array

   var_dump($this->errors);
}
```